# Getting wrong output while executing the spell check program

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm using this code for spelling correction. python version is 3.6.5. I'm executing this code in jupyter notebook.

code:

```
import os

import errno

from collections import Counter

from hashlib import sha256

import re

import json

import itertools

import logging

import requests

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

from numpy.random import choice as random_choice, randint as random_randint, 
shuffle as random_shuffle, seed as random_seed, rand

from numpy import zeros as np_zeros

from keras.models import Sequential, load_model

from keras.layers import Activation, TimeDistributed, Dense, RepeatVector, 
Dropout, recurrent

from keras.callbacks import Callback

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

LOGGER.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())

LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

random_seed(123)

class Configuration(object):

    CONFIG = Configuration()

    CONFIG.input_layers = 2

    CONFIG.output_layers = 2

    CONFIG.amount_of_dropout = 0.2

    CONFIG.hidden_size = 500

    CONFIG.initialization = "he_normal" 

    CONFIG.number_of_chars = 26

    CONFIG.max_input_len = 20

    CONFIG.inverted = True

    CONFIG.batch_size = 4

    CONFIG.epochs = 50

    CONFIG.steps_per_epoch = 10

    CONFIG.validation_steps = 10

    CONFIG.number_of_iterations = 10

dataset=pd.read_csv("inpspell_wordpair2.csv")

input_data=dataset['input'].tolist()

input_data1=str(input_data)

output_data=dataset['output'].tolist()

output_data1=str(output_data)

chars_input = set.union(*(set(input_data1) for inp in input_data1))

chars_output = set.union(*(set(output_data1) for op in output_data1))

chars = list(set.union(chars_input, chars_output))

chars=list(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

MIN_INPUT_LEN = 1

AMOUNT_OF_NOISE = 0.2 / CONFIG.max_input_len

CHARS = list(" abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ .")

class CharacterTable(object):

    def __init__(self, chars):

         self.chars = sorted(set(chars))

         self.char_indices = dict((c, i) for i, c in enumerate(self.chars))

         self.indices_char = dict((i, c) for i, c in enumerate(self.chars))

    @property
    def size(self):

        return len(self.chars)

    def encode(self, C, maxlen):
        X = np.zeros((maxlen, len(self.chars)), dtype=np.bool) # 
        for i, c in enumerate(C):
            X[i, self.char_indices[c]] = 1
    return X

    def decode(self, X, calc_argmax=True):
        if calc_argmax:
            X = X.argmax(axis=-1)
        return ''.join(self.indices_char[x] for x in X)

def _vectorize(questions, answers, ctable):

    len_of_questions = len(questions)

    X = np_zeros((len_of_questions, CONFIG.max_input_len, ctable.size),dtype=int)

    print("inputchars")

    for i in range(len(questions)):
        print(i)
        sentence = questions.pop()
        print(sentence)
        for j, c in enumerate(sentence):
            print(j,c)
            try:
                X[i, j, ctable.char_indices[c]] = 1
            except KeyError:
                pass 

    y = np_zeros((len_of_questions, CONFIG.max_input_len, ctable.size), 
dtype=int)
    print("outputchars")
    for i in range(len(answers)):
        print(i)
        sentence = answers.pop()
        print(sentence)
        for j, c in enumerate(sentence):
            try:
                y[i, j, ctable.char_indices[c]] = 1
            except KeyError:
                pass 
    return X, y

def vectorize(questions, answers, chars=None):

    print('Vectorization...')
    chars = chars or CHARS
    ctable = CharacterTable(chars)
    print("inputdata before _vec")
    print(questions)
    X, y = _vectorize(questions, answers, ctable)

    print(X.shape)
    print(y.shape)

    return  X, y, CONFIG.max_input_len, ctable

def generate_model(output_len, chars=None):

    print('Build model...')
    chars = chars or CHARS
    model = Sequential()

    for layer_number in range(CONFIG.input_layers):
        model.add(recurrent.LSTM(CONFIG.hidden_size, input_shape=(None, len(chars)), kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization, return_sequences=layer_number + 1 < CONFIG.input_layers))
        model.add(Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout))

    model.add(RepeatVector(output_len))

    for _ in range(CONFIG.output_layers):
        model.add(recurrent.LSTM(CONFIG.hidden_size, return_sequences=True, 
kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization))
        model.add(Dropout(CONFIG.amount_of_dropout))


    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(chars), kernel_initializer=CONFIG.initialization)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def iterate_training(model, X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val, ctable):

    for iteration in range(1, CONFIG.number_of_iterations):
        model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=CONFIG.batch_size, 
epochs=CONFIG.epochs, validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

X_train,y_train, y_maxlen, ctable = vectorize(input_data, output_data, 
chars)

print ("y_maxlen, chars", y_maxlen, "".join(chars))

model = generate_model(y_maxlen, chars)

iterate_training(model, X_train, y_train, X_train, y_train, ctable)

for inp in X_train:

    inputarray = ctable.decode(inp)

    print(inputarray)

prediction=model.predict_classes(X_train, verbose=0)

for p in prediction:

    guess = ctable.decode(p, calc_argmax=False)

    print(guess)

for op in y_train:

    correct = ctable.decode(op)

    print(correct)
```

For the above code i have taken a 50 samples of words as an input. But after executing i'm getting the correct word with the padding of last character of word till the maximum input length. The output is as shown below:

blangggggggggggggggg

accumulatorrrrrrrrrr

plateeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

pipeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

universallllllllllll

abrasiveeeeeeeelllll

wheellllllllllllllll

kittsiveeellllllllll

solidddddddddddddddd

the input words are:

blang
accumulator
plate
pipe
universal
abrasive
wheel
kit
solid

How can i overcome with this problem.

Comment: Can you please edit your post? Because some of your code seems like a normal text

Comment: Your code is wrongly indented